# ActiveRecord where statement selecting fields from nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Given

```
class Foo
  has_many :bar
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

I want:

```
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Foo id: 11, qux: 'hi', bar_id: 1, bar_name: 'blah', bar_something: 'blahblah' >, #<Foo id: 23, qux: 'hi', bar_id: 2, bar_name: 'lorem', bar_something: 'ipsum' >]>
```

I can do this:

```
> Foo.where(qux: 'hi').includes(:bar)
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Foo id: 11, qux: 'hi', bar_id: 1 >, #<Foo id: 23, qux: 'hi', bar_id: 2 >]>
```

But it does not load the child records. It seems just to hold on to it in case it's needed.

There must be something more elegant than this?

```
Foo.where(qux: 'hi').includes(:bar).to_a.map do | f |
  f.keys.each { |k| f[ k.to_s ] = f.delete(k) if k.class == :symbol }
  Bar.column_names.except('id','foo_id').each do | ba |
    ba_name = 'bar_' + ba
    f.merge({ba_name => f.bar.send(ba.to_sym)})
  end
  f
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`includes(:bar)` lazy loads the child records, in this case `bar`. It's one way to avoid n+1 queries (so that you don't run one query for each instance of `foo`). And you do have access to it.

```
Foo.where(qux: 'hi').each do |foo|
  puts foo.bar.inspect
end
```

If you want to get all `foos` where their `bar.qux = hi`, then go the otherway:

```
Bar.joins(:foo).where(foo: { qux: 'hi' })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo.select("foos.id,foos.qux,bar_id,bars.bar_name,bars.something").joins(:bar).where(qux: 'hi')
```

`includes` lazy load the association so it basically does not merge both tables. What you are looking can be done through `joins` which allow you to query on both tables and select all required columns which you want. You can find more help here http://tomdallimore.com/blog/includes-vs-joins-in-rails-when-and-where/

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Hatchet thanks for kind reminder I have updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Do you actually need the AR relation to have all those values loaded up-front?  The lazy loading is intentional to keep you from beating up the DB unnecessarily...

You can still reference any attribute of bar directly:

```
Foo.where(qux: 'hi').includes(:bar).each do |foo|
  puts foo.bar.name   # This will actually load bar from the DB
end
```

There aren't usually great reasons for overriding this, especially if the dataset could be large-ish.